# Install CryptoTE for 14.04 (trusty)

Tags: 14.04, password, encryption

I am trying to install CryptoTE on 14.04 (trusty) using these instructions which are for 12.04.

[Link to CryptoTE, Instructions](http://panthema.net/2009/cryptote/linux-binary.html#ubuntu)

First is this:

```
wget -O- https://panthema.net/repo/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then an edit is made to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu precise main
```

Where it says `precise` I made it `trusty` because I am using 14.04. Then the `apt-get update` is next:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The following errors are observed.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

I had previously used CryptoTE on 14.04 but that system was a 12.04 upgraded to 14.04. Now I'm on a fresh install of 14.04 and I still need CryptoTE. It is my password keeper.

Comment: please try my answer and comment  result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install CryptoTE on trusty (14.04), as per the [original instructions](http://panthema.net/2009/cryptote/linux-binary.html#ubuntu)

```
wget -O- https://panthema.net/repo/key.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

then just make the edit, adding a line, to

`/etc/apt/sources.list`

as follows, naming `precise` instead of `trusty`.

```
deb http://panthema.net/repo/ubuntu precise main
```

This can get CryptoTE installed and running even though the operating system does not match. It will be running without adverse consequences if trusty is compatible with precise applications, in general, or specifically with respect to CryptoTE.

The [CryptoTE website](http://panthema.net/2009/cryptote/linux-binary.html#ubuntu) shows that CryptoTE evolved as Ubuntu evolved, but does not necessarily imply that the above suggestion will fail because a new version of CryptoTE is necessary for trusty.

If this suggestion is followed, the third worst thing that could happen is that valuable data will be inaccessible, LOL, until somebody obtains the source code, which is readily available, at least at the present time, and modifies the program for trusty.

The second worst thing that could happen is that CryptoTE runs in a buggy way that allows you to add data that will later become inaccessible.

The worst thing is that CryptoTE runs in a buggy way and that the source code becomes unavailable.

Comment: The developer of CryptoTE has just sent me an email saying that this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and run:

```
suo add-apt-repository ppa:bingmann/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cryptote
```

**Note**: Before update,open software & Updates then Other software tab,uncheck the repos creating error or remove the entry added to `/etc/apt/sources.list`